# ValueError: operation parameter must be str (deleting record from database)

Tags: python, sqlite

i am trying to create a function that can remove a student from the database i created.

```
def remove_students():
        cursor = db.cursor()
        first_name = input("Enter first name: ")
        surname = input("Enter surname:  ")
        year_group = int(input("Enter year group: "))
        student_info = (first_name, surname, year_group)
        cursor.execute(student_info, remove_student)
        db.commit()

sql_2 = """CREATE TABLE students(
        ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        first_name TEXT,
        Surname TEXT,
        year_group INTEGER,
        strike INTEGER,);"""

remove_student = "DELETE FROM students (first_name, surname, year_group) values (?,?,?)"
```

when i run this code i get this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "M:\computer science a2\comp 3\login.py", line 112, in remove_students
    cursor.execute(student_info, remove_student)
ValueError: operation parameter must be str
```

i dont understand because i have added int before the entry for the year group. any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in `cursor.execute(student_info, remove_student)`

It should be cursor.execute(remove_student, student_info)

Here is the modified method!

```
def remove_students():
    cursor = db.cursor()
    first_name = input("Enter first name: ")
    surname = input("Enter surname:  ")
    year_group = int(input("Enter year group: "))
    student_info = (first_name, surname, year_group)
    #cursor.execute(sql_query,params)
    cursor.execute(remove_student, student_info)
    db.commit()
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Are you sure? Can you please share the updated code as an image here to the question adding as an edit!

Comment: oh no... sorry it did fox the problem but now i get a new error message saying:   cursor.execute(remove_student, student_info)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error

Comment: Check the syntax of tumour sql query. Delete query syntax can be used with where clause. I ain't sure if it can be used the way you've done. Kindly check that.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
cursor.execute(student_info, remove_student)
```

inside your function. I think it should be:

```
cursor.execute(remove_student, student_info)
```

"operation" is the first positional parameter (you had it second).

Comment: DB-API’s parameter substitution use `?` as placeholder. So that isn't the problem!